# error trying to use cv2.imshow

Tags: python, image, opencv, computer-vision

when I'm using `cv2.imshow` like this:

```
import numpy as np

import cv2

img = cv2.imread('galaxy.jpg',0)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

I get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file -------src-dir-------/opencv-2.4.10/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 501
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: -------src-dir-------/opencv-2.4.10/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:501: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage
```

P.S.  just edited the programming part code. thanks to stackoverflow feedback

Comment: The error is rather explicit. You need to have GTK or Carbon support (or be on windows).

Comment: which OS do you use?

Comment: To do code formatting, put 4 spaces before each line of code. The easy way to do this is to select the lines of code and hit ctrk-k. That will indent the entire selected block for you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @Micka i'm using ubuntu 14.04 lts. with Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)| GCC 4.4.7 20120313

Comment: @y300 what are these GTK or Carbon support

Comment: as it is said in the error message: `If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script`

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you built the OpenCV lib yourself using Cmake? Then you forgot to switch on some necessary flags (apparently GTK support). You will have to rebuild the lib with the correct compiler flags enabled. To help you do that, there is a "getting started" page for python on the OpenCV official website.

Comment: I install Opencv by myself right, but I exactly followed the instruction mentioned in [link]  (http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/) in cmake part i didn't see anything mentioning gtk. also in [link] (http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation)  and [link] (http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_intro/py_intro.html#intro)i don't see any thing in official site of opencv

Comment: again, get gtk2 (not 3), and try with `cmake -DWITH_GTK=ON`

Comment: Is there any way to do this configuration if you have built OpenCV using conda?